# Do I search a query on the web or search for a query?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I search somewhere for something I want to find.  So I search my house for my keys.  What about a query I type in the search bar?

> I search "what is ve day" on Google

or,

> I search for "what is ve day" on Google

Comment: The main problem I see in your examples is that the verb *search* should be in the past - *searched*. Of the two you gave, I would prefer the second. If I were to start from scratch, I would probably go with `I searched for "ve day" in my browser` or `I tried searching for "ve day" on DuckDuckGo` or even `I did a web search for "ve day".`

Answer (score 1):

Personally, whenever I explain a search query *verbatim* to someone, I don't use "*for*":

> I searched "How old is Leonardo DiCaprio" on Google...

Essentially, I'm treating the full search like direct speech.

When one merely states the topic/person/object that they searched for, I feel like without the word "*for*," the sentence doesn't seem quite right.

> I searched **for** *cat images* on Google.
>
> I searched **for** *Leonardo Dicaprio's age* on Google.

Maybe this is governed by personal preference; I'm not too sure.